# MVC Routing with parentheses

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've following URL in my application.

```
http://localhost:62082/DynamicPages/UserTemplates(b1078ccd-7d24-40c9-947b-883d047b31cf)
```

I want to write routing to get value inside parentheses. I've the following code. But it doesn't work.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Templates",
            url: "DynamicPages/{action}({id})",
            defaults: new { controller = "DynamicPages", action = "EditTemplates", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Is there any other way to do with MVC?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: try url: "DynamicPages/{action}(/{id})",

Comment: You might have to go for a custom route parsing, like this one http://erraticdev.blogspot.fr/2011/01/custom-aspnet-mvc-route-class-with.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for this.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Templates",
        url: "DynamicPages/UserTemplates({id})",
        defaults: new { controller = "DynamicPages", action = "EditTemplates", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define the action such as

```
@Html.Action("bla bla","bla bla",{new id=something+"?value="+something})
```

you can define how many you want with `?value=`